# How to use EKS with suitable volumes and resolve subnet IP insufficient issue on AWS?

Tags: amazon-eks

I deployed an application in EKS. The deployment always pending, when I checked the events found these issues.

```
$ kubectl get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                         MESSAGE
89s         Warning   FailedScheduling    pod/awx-demo-111111111-122222   running PreBind plugin "VolumeBinding": binding volumes: provisioning failed for PVC "awx-demo-projects-claim"
49m         Warning   FailedDeployModel   ingress/awx-demo-ingress        Failed deploy model due to InvalidSubnet: Not enough IP space available in subnet-031f9c702bc474e8f. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet.
            status code: 400, request id: 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
32m         Warning   FailedDeployModel   ingress/awx-demo-ingress        Failed deploy model due to InvalidSubnet: Not enough IP space available in subnet-01322i912fas0123na. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet.
            status code: 400, request id: 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555515
15m         Warning   FailedDeployModel   ingress/awx-demo-ingress        Failed deploy model due to InvalidSubnet: Not enough IP space available in subnet-031f9c702bc474e8f. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet.
            status code: 400, request id: 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555525
89s         Normal    WaitForPodScheduled   persistentvolumeclaim/awx-demo-projects-claim   waiting for pod awx-demo-111111111-122222 to be scheduled
21m         Warning   ProvisioningFailed    persistentvolumeclaim/awx-demo-projects-claim   Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2": invalid AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce] are supported
```

It seems there are device issue and subnet issue. I created the EKS cluster and node group with these configurations:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
  encryption_config {
    resources = ["secrets"]
    provider {
      key_arn = aws_kms_key.this.arn
    }
  }

  enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "authenticator", "audit", "scheduler", "controllerManager"]
  name                      = local.cluster_name
  version                   = "1.20"
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [
      data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_0_id.value,
      data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_1_id.value,
    ]

    security_group_ids     = [aws_security_group.this.id]
    endpoint_public_access = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_cluster_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_vpc_resource_controller,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_service_policy,
  ]

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
  )
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "this" {
  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  node_group_name = local.node_group_name
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.arn
  instance_types  = ["m5.2xlarge"]

  subnet_ids = [
    data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_0_id.value,
    data.aws_ssm_parameter.private_subnet_1_id.value,
  ]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 2
    min_size     = 2
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [scaling_config[0].desired_size]
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_worker_node_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_cni_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ec2_container_register_readonly,
  ]

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
  )
}
```

I didn't define the volume type for EBS, maybe it's using the default setting. How to fix the issue?

For the VPC has insufficient IP addresses issue, if create a new subnet for EKS to use, is it necessary to delete the EKS cluster or node group?

By the way, the deployment I used was https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/awx-operator/0.13.0/deploy/awx-operator.yaml.
The install was used https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator#basic-install.

Comment: what size subnets is your EKS launched in ?

Comment: @YYashwanth /27

Comment: Yeah.. thats 32 IPs out of which 5 are reserved for AWS. So you only have 27 IPs and if ELB needs 8 IPs per subnets, you are left with 19 IPs but the nodes, pods etc take up the IPs right ? That might be the reason. Can you increase the subnet size to a /25 or /24 ? I have created and maintained many production EKS clusters and always assign a /24 to allow for teams to scale up.

Comment: @YYashwanth Thank you. If I create a new subnet with /24 size, do I need to recreate the EKS cluster use the new subnet again? And, do you know something about the volume issue? Maybe they can be resolved together for the cluster setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@miantian, Continuing our discussion from the comments:

A subnet size cannot just be increased. If you change the subnet size, it will be recreated. But as the EKS is there, the subnet creation will fail. So, I would say - start fresh. Delete everything and then start fresh.

Regd the volume issue, by default EKS only supports ReadWriteOnce access mode. This is because of the technical limitation of AWS where an EBS volume can only be attached to 1 EC2 instance. If you want to use ReadWriteMany access mode, you need to use EFS.

If you want to use EFS, look up NFS/EFS client provisioner for EKS. There are few steps you need to follow in order to create an EFS provisioner in EKS. Then, you can start using ReadWriteMany access mode.

Comment: Thank you for that. About EFS, I think the few steps are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).